# Calculate memory used by an application through coding

Tags: android

I displayed a list of RunningAppProcesses using getRunningAppProcesses.

Instead of displaying processNames, I would like to display Application Labels. 
So I used getApplicationLabel to obtain the application LABEL.

So for the processName com.android.music, the label was Music. But for the process android.process.media, I cannot retrieve LABEL.

Though I understood that android.process.media is being used by Music App (since i played music just before running this app), how can I group these two processes as being used by Music App?

Similarly for other applications how can I find out the processes which are running because of a particular application so that I can group them and try to calculate the total memory used by the application by summing the memory used by those processes..?

Kindly help...
(I tried to describe my query well, but if it is not clear please excuse me and give suggestions since I am new to android and to stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can't. The 'android.process.media' process (and Linux user that the process belongs to) is the media playback component of the Android OS, and responsible for all kinds of work - for instance, it downloads and plays video content in the YouTube app, rather than this being done by the YouTube app/user itself as you may have thought.

This is an unusual case - although there are other examples - and unless you can confidently determine that media's appearance is linked to some other app, my suggestion is to ignore it.

Comment: So can I just ignore it and calculate the memory used by the application by calculating memory used by com.android.music alone?

Comment: The media process will have the memory assigned to it, but as it stands you can't be sure that it can be attributed to Music rather than YouTube or anything else. Therefore your stats will be 'wrong' in practical terms but better than trying to guess.  If it were me I would write a special case for media - give it a label like 'Android Media Player' and show it as its own process.

Comment: But I don't understand how task manager apps or Android emulator settings calculate and show memory used by applications....